# How can i get all image urls from my nasa api and add them into an image slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my component of imageslider with button next and previous
I need som help how i can get individual img_src values and add them into another array and them use them in my image slider.

I welcome every solution corresponding to my aproach

````
const ImageSlider = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const ImageList = useSelector((state) => state.ImageList);

  const { loading, error, Images } = ImageList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(ListImages());
  }, [dispatch]);

  var items = [Images.photos];

  console.log(Images);

  const classes = useStyles();

  function Item(props) {
    return (
      <Paper>
        {props.item.map(data => (
         <img src={data.img_src} />
        ))}
      

        {({ onClick, className, style, next, prev }) => {
          return (
            <Button onClick={onClick} className={classes.button} style={style}>
              {next && "Next"}
              {prev && "Previous"}
            </Button>
          );
        }}
      </Paper>
    );
  }
 return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <h1>{error}</h1>
      ) : (
        <Carousel>
          {items.map((item, i) => (
            <Item key={i} item={item} />
          ))}
        </Carousel>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageSlider;
```
````

Comment: Break this into smaller pieces. Are you able to get the url for a single image and then display it? If not, then start by figuring that part out. Break it into even smaller pieces, too. If you can do that much, then find the next small piece you can try to add to what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should move the Item component out of the ImageSlider. It is being redefined every render. You can use localState to keep track of the index.

```
const useImageIndexer = (maxIndex) => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const nextImage = () => {
        setIndex((current) => Math.min(maxIndex, current + 1));
    };
    const prevImage = () => {
        setIndex((current) => Math.max(0, current - 1));
    };
    return [index, nextImage, prevImage];
}
```

Then to use inside the slider

```
const ImageSlider = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const ImageList = useSelector((state) => state.ImageList);
      const photos = ImageList.Images.photos;
      const [index, nextImage, prevImage] = useImageIndexer(photos.length);
      const currentPhoto = photos[index];

     // Further down in the code
    
     if(loading) {
         return (<Loader />);
     }
     if (error) {
         return (<div>Oh no!</div>);
     }

     return (<div>
       <img src={img.src} />
       <button onClick={prevImage}>Previous</button>
       <button onClick={nextImage}>Next</button>
      </div>);
```

It seemed like you were wrapping photos which sounds like an array inside another array, that doesn't look right.

```
  var items = [Images.photos];
```

Comment: And how do u call it in the return jsx of the imagelsider

Comment: @starreelzVEVO I've edit the solution to include some JSX.
In future refrain from asking for fully coded solutions. You should be able to figure out the basics and ask more specific questions. Really you are asking more than one question.